# cassandra: Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.6.jar

Tags: java, server, cassandra-2.1

I am working on *[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.1 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]*  from last 5 month on centOS 7 server.

Unfortunately server got off. After that i am trying to restart the cassandra.

```
$ cassandra
```

But got the error

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.6.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to point CASSANDRA_HOME to "C:\cassandra107" rather than "C:\cassandra107\bin" and start cassandra as "bin\cassandra" in "C:\cassandra107"